# How to assign the column number to a parameter

Tags: anylogic

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/3CI1x.jpg)

In the screenshot, you can see a datatable. My problem is to assign the column number with sum zero to a parameter. I can add individual column

```
selectFirstValue("SELECT SUM(c1) FROM precedence;");
```

with this code and find out its sum.

Here is my datatable name is "precedence".

Now is it possible to do this column sum in a loops are any other way where it makes the sum of each column and assign the column number to a parameter when its sum is zero. In my case I will only have one column with sum zero.

Comment: Either load all data into Java class elements and do the calculations there. Or pre-calculate before even importing. Doing any analysis with SQL is not worth the pain :)

Comment: Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.